# Manually setting date time in Lubuntu does not update the hardware clock

Tags: ubuntu, time, clock

Lubuntu is not changing the bios date-time when I set the date-time manually using the Time and Date Application. Due to which, when I reboot it synchronises the time with the wrong time in bios.

I am not using ntp.

I tried putting the following command on various places.

```
hwclock --systohc --localtime
```

I placed it in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` int session-cleanup-script (P.S called the command using script);

I placed it in `/etc/init.d/` and created symlinks in `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d/`.

OS is Lubuntu 16.04

I cannot issue command from terminal as the OS will be deployed to non-technical users.

Comment: What have you tried?  

 1. List the commands that you issued to the shell.
 2. Show the contents of the `ntp.conf` file by typing: `cat /etc/ntp.conf`

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: are you testing on metal or inside a VM ?

Comment: is it possible the desktop  ... Gnome clock is not updating the new time ? check if hwclock shows the correct time

Comment: I have tested on both in vm and metal. I checked using timedatectl | head -3 command and can confirm that system time is changing but not the hwclock

Comment: Does `hwclock --systohc` work when you invoke it manually?  Is the only problem that you're trying to figure out where to put that invocation so it happens automatically every time the clock is set and/or the system is shut down?

Comment: manually running hwclock --systohc works. And yes that is the only problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modifing the /etc/sudoers file by appending the following.

%sudo ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/hwclock